# MySQL INNER vs LEFT JOIN different order

Tags: php, mysql

Why do this two queries return different result set when they have the same ORDER BY.

Only difference in query is that first time I user INNER JOIN an it takes about 5 seconds.
Second time I used LEFT JOIN and it took 0.05 seconds. In both cases they return exactly 43.000 rows, but tck.id order is different and I can't figure out why or in which way?

```
SELECT tck.*, acc.ac_name
FROM support_tickets tck  
INNER JOIN support_ticket_accounts acc USING (id_support_ticket_account)
WHERE tck.id_company = 2 AND tck.st_status = 1 ORDER BY tck.st_priority DESC
```

Edit:

```
SELECT tck.*, acc.ac_name
FROM support_tickets tck
    LEFT JOIN support_ticket_accounts acc ON tck.id_support_ticket_account = acc.id_support_ticket_account
WHERE tck.id_company = 2 AND tck.st_status = 1
ORDER BY tck.st_priority DESC;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                           | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tck   | ref    | id_company    | id_company | 5       | const                         | 37586 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acc   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | tck.id_support_ticket_account |     1 |                             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+

SELECT tck.*, acc.ac_name
FROM support_tickets tck
    INNER JOIN support_ticket_accounts acc ON tck.id_support_ticket_account = acc.id_support_ticket_account
WHERE tck.id_company = 2 AND tck.st_status = 1
ORDER BY tck.st_priority DESC;
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                        | key                       | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acc   | ALL  | PRIMARY                              | NULL                      | NULL    | NULL                          |    5 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tck   | ref  | id_company,id_support_ticket_account | id_support_ticket_account | 5       | acc.id_support_ticket_account | 2085 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: left join with where is nothing but will behave as inner join, as far as time is concern it could be the query cache. Try using left join first and then inner join and see the time taken.

Comment: Could you provide output of `EXPLAIN` for both queries?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty There's no WHERE condition on `acc`

Comment: Unless specified, the order in which rows are returned is arbitrary (even if it seems otherwise). Also, I think USING is confUSING (especially on larger queries). I avoid it.

Comment: I have edited post with EXPLAIN. @Strawbery, thanks for clarification. So basically I have to add another order by to get what I want?
I have read somewhere that USING is faster, but I also like it more as in edited part. It doesn't influence performance in this case.
I'm still wondering why mysql "optimizes" 2nd query to take 5 seconds :-/

Comment: Faster? I'm sure the optimizer 'optimizes' it into oblivion!

Answer (score 1):

If you just `ORDER BY tck.st_priority DESC` multiple different recordsets are posible and can be returned, for each of both cases (left or inner). That is because you must have a lot of records that has the same `st_priority` so any of them can came in no particular order
Add more fields to the order by clause to give any record unique possible position and you will have same order on both querys.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`using temporary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) is responsible for the delay (but I don't see why it's necessary for one query and not the other one). I think creating [multi-column index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) should help:

```
CREATE INDEX filter 
    ON support_tickets(id_company, st_status, st_priority)
    USING BTREE;
```